# Splashscreen on linux platform using java

Tags: java, swing, splash-screen

I was trying to launch the splash-screen on linux Ubuntu v10.x. But the `SplashScreen` class's method is returning `null`

```
SplashScreen.getSplashScreen()
```

What should possibly be the reason??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [doc also says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html):

> This class cannot be instantiated. Only a single instance of this class can exist, and it may be obtained using the getSplashScreen() static method. **In case the splash screen has not been created at application startup via the command line or manifest file option, the getSplashScreen method returns null.**

Here is the manifest example:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Test
SplashScreen-Image: filename.gif
```

And here the command-line example:

```
java -splash:filename.gif Test
```

Answer (score 2):

The [doc says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html#getSplashScreen%28%29):

Returns:
    the SplashScreen instance, *or null if there is none or it has already been closed*

(my emphasis). Does this apply ?

Comment: "or NULL if there is none", which means that the OS does not have a splash screen?But in that case it has to throw an Exception: UnsupportedOperationException - if the splash screen feature is not supported by the current toolkit, but its not giving an exception!!

Comment: @KDjava No, it returns null if you have not set any splashscreen, that's all.